# Nativescript/Angular2: Attribute binding [text] on Button doesn't work - not updated when bool changes

Tags: angular, data-binding, nativescript

From the Groceries tutorial, they have buttons with text, like this:

[image]

There is an attribute binding, like this:

```js
<Button [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign in' : 'Sign up'" class="submit-button" (tap)="submit()"></Button>
<Button [text]="isLoggingIn ? 'Sign up' : 'Back to login'" (tap)="toggleDisplay()"></Button>
```

and in the component:

```js
@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
//   providers: [LoginService],
  templateUrl: "./pages/login/login.html",
  styleUrls: ["./pages/login/login-common.css", "./pages/login/login.css"]
})
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
//   loginRequest: Login;
  isLoggingIn = true;
  @ViewChild("container") container: ElementRef;

  constructor(
    private router: Router, private page: Page) 
    {
       //....
    }
    
    // ....
  toggleDisplay() 
  {
    this.isLoggingIn = !this.isLoggingIn;
    let container = <View>this.container.nativeElement;
    container.animate({
      backgroundColor: this.isLoggingIn
        ? new Color("white")
        : new Color("#301217"),
      duration: 200
    });
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.page.actionBarHidden = true;
    this.page.backgroundImage = "res://bg_login";
  }
}
```

Problem 1: There is no text at all when the app is started when I run it:

[image]

Problem 2: When I press the grey button, the animation happens, but the text isn't changed or made visible.

I had it working a day or so ago, but I had to rebuild the tutorial since I npm:ed the project to death. Now, I cannot understand why the binding does not fire.

Comment: try not use [text], simple: < button...>{{isLoggingIn ? 'Sign in' : 'Sign up'}}< /button>

Comment: Nops, same situation - no text, no changes. And it would be weird if the [text] didnt work, its in the tutorial here: https://docs.nativescript.org/angular/tutorial/ng-chapter-3 ... and I actually got it to work before. Dunno exactly why it stopped working...

Comment: ::glups:: you're asking about NativeScript, I thinked that your question was about only Angular, sorry for the confusion

Comment: No worries. I have a hard time distinguishing between whats-what, to be honest ;-)

Comment: UPDATE: I didnt change anything more than just, changing the output string on the button and saving, and suddenly, it works again. Out of nowhere...